# Queries about why $p: S^1 \to S^1$ such that $p(z)=z^n$ is a covering map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

To understand why this is true I have been told to imagine the covering space as 
..."drawing a circle wrapping around a cylinder $n$ times with $(n-1)$ intersections".

The covering space $p: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ defined as $p(x)=(\cos 2 \pi x, \sin 2 \pi x)$ makes sense to me because all we are doing is finding all the values $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which map to the same point on $S^1$.

So, we can just draw a line and easily demonstrate these intervals. We do not need to imagine $\mathbb{R}$ as anything else.

I am confused as to why we are now imagining $S^1$ as something else then $S^1$.

I am sorry if my question is confusing. Anyways, I would just appreciate a clear answer as to why this is a covering space.

Comment: Perhaps just imagine it as a circle wrapping around another circle $n-1$ times, if that is clearer. Anyway, it's a covering space because it satisfies the definition of a covering space. Have you worked through the verification?

Comment: Is your confusion with the definition of $z^n$ here? Note that we're identifying $S^1$ with the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, so multiplication of two elements of $S^1$ makes sense.

Comment: There is a sort of standard picture that belongs to the given map $p$: imagine an infinite spring hovering above a circle. The circle $S^1$ is then covered by this coiled up real line. Does it help to imagine what the given map does to this spring? I don't really get the impression you look at $S^1$ in any different way.

Comment: @Potato, How will these intervals every be disjoint? For example, if we look at $(1,0)$, applying $p$ to it will just give us back the same point, and therefore the same open neighborhood around it.

Comment: @HSN, In my weak understanding,  $S^1$ is supposed to be covered by $S^1$ and not an infinite spring. We covered $S^1$ by $\mathbb{R}$, we didn't "change" $\mathbb{R}$ in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested, it seems appropriate to get away from the confusing attempt at an intuitive picture and simply prove something. Thus let's forget all ideas about cylinders and springs.

For simplicity take $n=2$. Then the inverse image of a point $e^{i\theta}$ in $S^1$ is $\{e^{i\theta/2},e^{i(\theta/2+\pi)}\}$. In particular, inverse images are discrete. Let's show that $1$ is covered. Indeed, the inverse image of $S^1\setminus \{-1\}$ is the disjoint union of $\{e^{ i\theta}:\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\}$ and $\{e^{ i\theta}:\theta\in(-3\pi/2,-\pi/2)\}$, both of which are mapped homeomorphically onto $S^1\setminus \{-1\}$. A similar argument works to show $z^n$ covers at different points and for different $n$.

Let me attempt, anyway, to clarify the intuitive picture you've been given: it should look like the following, where $p$ is the covering map and $L$ is some point in the base circle $S$. This picture does make it obvious for many people that $p$ is covering, since the inverse image of a small enough interval around $L$ is the union of two intervals on the locally-distinct components of the covering circle lying above $L$. You could draw it on the cylinder as you've been advised, but then you'd have to remember that an apparent intersection in the fiber over $L$ wasn't really there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the depiction. I am, however, still confused, shouldn't $S^1$ cover $S^1$? The "helix" type image is not $S^1$ so why is this the covering?

Comment: The "helix" is homeomorphic to $S^1$: just undo the twist over $L$. In topology homeomorphism type is all that matters. I don't think you can prove that this is a covering map in full detail without understanding arithmetic of complex numbers, but the fact I'm using is that $(e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta}$. You can verify my claim using this fact: just compute the squares of elements of the two components in my claimed inverse image.

Comment: Thank you! It is starting to make more sense. I didn't know that the helix and the circle would be homeomorphic.

Comment: Of course-it may have been a matter of the picture being unclear.

Comment: Just one more question. Why is the inverse image $\{e^{i \theta}, e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2} + \pi} \}$ ? Can you give the example when $n=3$? I could probably figure this out for myself from there.

Comment: Note you have a typo there. The inverse image is as I wrote it because $(e^{i\theta/2})^2=e^{i\theta}$ and $(e^{i(\theta/2+\pi)})^2=e^{i(\theta+2\pi)}=e^{i\theta}e^{i2\pi}$ and $e^{i2\pi }=\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)=1$. For $n=3$ we get $\{e^{i\theta/3},e^{i\theta/3+2\pi/3},e^{i\theta/3+4\pi/3}\}.$